# False positive with SonarQube pl/sql rule plsql:S3633

Tags: plsql, sonarqube

The pl/sql rule plsql:S3633 detects a false positive when query is not coded with ANSI norm:

[image]

First line is the join condition and second a filter.

Please, can you check, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm this is a false positive with SonarPLSQL 3.2.
A ticket has be created [SONARPLSQL-664](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPLSQL-664) to fix it in the next version.